# Storing Passwords for Third Party Services

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, encryption, ruby-on-rails-3

My application is ruby-on-rails, but I expect any answers to this question will probably be framework agnostic.

My application sends emails via gmail SMTP using rails ActionMailers a-la:

```
mail = MyActionMailerSubclass.setup_email

options = { :address          => "smtp.gmail.com",
        :port                 => 587,
        :domain               => 'mydomain.com',
        :user_name            => 'myuser@mydomain.com',
        :password             => 's3cur3p@s$w0rd',
        :authentication       => 'plain',
        :enable_starttls_auto => true  }

mail.delivery_method :smtp, options
mail.deliver
```

Ok, that's great...there's my password for gmail in plain text in the application code.  Or I could store it in the database in plain text.  Obviously both are unacceptable.

Salting and hashing, the usual technique wont work here because I need to send the password along to gmail.

So, what strategies are there for securing a password for a third party service?

Ultimately that user name and password wont even belong to me, they will belong to the application end-user.

Answer (score 4):

Gmail's SMTP server supports two authentication mechanisms: PLAIN and XOAUTH. The PLAIN mechanism requires that you know the user's plaintext password, and I'm glad you aren't prepared to store those.

Take a look at the [OAuth](https://code.google.com/apis/gmail/oauth/protocol.html) protocol as used by Gmail. I haven't ever used it and I just found out that Gmail supports it for SMTP, so I can't help any further, but I'd say that's precisely what you want. OAuth is a way for a service (such as Gmail) to allow third-party services (such as yours) to perform a limited set of actions on behalf of users without logging in with their password.

Answer (score 0):

If the application is private then this should be of no concern, but I'm guessing it's for a public / open-source application.

If that is the case, then add a basic example of that file as *config/initializers/mail.rb.example* and add the real thing to your *.gitignore* file so that it's never committed. After that, add instructions to the *README* that people will need to copy over the *mail.rb.example* file to *mail.rb* in order for the application to work as intended.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, that helps in the case where other coders are involved.  My real concern is that the end user will be doing the emailing from their account.  So I need a way for them to store their credentials.

Comment: That approach will help the OP hide his *own* password from open-source users. I think what he is concerned about is more that he'll have to store *his* users' passwords on his server in plaintext, and doesn't want the responsibility.